# What's the best candidate padding char for url-safe and filename-safe base64?

Tags: encoding, base64, padding

The padding char for the official base64 is '=', which might need to be percent-encoded when used in a URL. I'm trying to find the best padding char so that my encoded string can be both url safe (I'll be using the encoded string as parameter value, such as id=encodedString) AND filename safe (I'll be using the encoded string directly as filename).

Dot ('.') is a popular candidate, it's url safe but it's not exactly filename safe: [Windows won't allow a file name which ends with a trailing dot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx).

'!' seems to be a viable choice, although I googled and I've never seen anybody using it as the padding char. Any ideas? Thanks!

**Update**: I replaced "+" with "-" (minus) and replaced "/" with "_" (underscore) in my customized base64 encoding already, so '-' or '_' is not available for the padding char any more.

Answer (score 4):

The best solution (I've spent last month working on this problem with an email sending website) is to not use padding character (=) at all

The only reason why padding character is there is because of "lazy" decoders. You can extremely easy add missing = -> just do %4 on text and subtract the number you get from 4 and that is how many = you need to add in string end. Here is C# code:

```
    var pad = 4 - (text.Length % 4);
    if (pad < 4)
        text = text.PadRight(text.Length + pad, '=');
```

Also, most people who do this are interested in replacing + and / with other URL safe character... I propose:

- replace with -
  / replace with _

DO NOT USE . as it can produce crazy results on different systems / web servers (for example on IIS Base64 encoded string can't end with . or IIS will search for the file)

Comment: Not quite correct, the result of the padding is not divisible by 4. Need to append (4-pad) number of '=' characters not pad number. Otherwise neat solution.

Comment: @YoungBob I've edited answer, please edit it if you can propose better code. Thanks!

Comment: In Python you can do simply `text + (-len(text) % 4) * "="` but this way of calculating it cannot be used in other languages (the % operator in Python gives a positive value for a positive divisor).

Answer (score 2):

The [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) unreserved characters in URIs are:

```
"-" | "_" | "." | "!" | "~" | "*" | "'" | "(" | ")"
```

It's worth pointing out, though, that the Microsoft article also says "Do not assume case sensitivity."  Perhaps you should just stick with base 16 or 32?

Comment: I would avoid . ~ * ' ( ) for filenames though

Comment: Thanks Miles, seems like '!' is good for both url and file name. Maybe I'll go with base32 with '!' as the padding char.

Answer (score 1):

The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications) article states;

> a modified Base64 for URL variant
>   exists, where no padding '=' will be
>   used

Answer (score 0):

I would go with '-' or '_'
They're URL and file safe, and they looks more or less like padding

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned this:
I replaced "+" with "-" (minus) and replaced "/" with "_" (underscore) in my customized base64 encoding already, so '-' or '_' is not available for the padding char any more.