# Encrypting an id in an URL in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, encryption

I'm attempting to encode the encrypted id in the Url. Like this: *http://www.calemadr.com/Membership/Welcome/9xCnCLIwzxzBuPEjqJFxC6XJdAZqQsIDqNrRUJoW6229IIeeL4eXl5n1cnYapg+N*

However, it either doesn't encode correctly and I get slashes '/' in the encryption or I receive and error from IIS: **The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence.**

I've tried different encodings, each fails:

- HttpUtility.HtmlEncode
- HttpUtility.UrlEncode
- HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode
- HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode

**Update**

The problem was I when I encrypted a Guid and converted it to a base64 string it would contain unsafe url characters . Of course when I tried to navigate to a url containing unsafe characters IIS(7.5/ windows 7) would blow up. Url Encoding the base64 encrypted string would raise and error in IIS (*The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence.*). I'm not sure how it detects double encoded strings but it did.

After trying the above methods to encode the base64  encrypted string. I decided to remove the base64 encoding.  However this leaves the encrypted text as a byte[]. I tried UrlEncoding the byte[], it's one of the overloads hanging off the httpUtility.Encode method. Again, while it was URL encoded, IIS did not like it and served up a *"page not found."*

After digging around the net I came across a [HexEncoding/Decoding](http://bimalesh.blogspot.com/2006/11/c-class-for-hex-encoding.html) class. 
Applying the Hex Encoding to the encrypted bytes did the trick. The output is url safe. On the other side, I haven't had any problems with decoding and decrypting the hex strings.

Comment: Your Update is way better than answer. And if you want Base64 encoded URLs that are safe, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10858198/237858

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wrote a short blog [post](http://toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2009/09/25/How-to-encrypt-a-query-string-in-aspnet-mvc/) about this very topic including full source code.

It enables you to encrypt and decrypt data stored in query string form using a 16 char key :

> I found a great set of base classes to solve this but for the most
>   part it comes down to one class. This class requires a 16 char key of
>   some kind to do the encryption and a value to encrypt. You can also
>   set an expiration value if needed.

```
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Security;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using EncryptionMVC.Security.Encryption.Utility.Interfaces;
using EncryptionMVC.Security.Encryption.Utility;
namespace Security.Encryption.QueryString
{
    /// 
    /// Provides a secure means for transfering data within a query string.
    /// 
    public class SecureQueryString : NameValueCollection
    {

        private string timeStampKey = '__TS__';
        private string dateFormat = 'G';
        private IEncryptionUtility mEncryptionUtil;
        private DateTime m_expireTime = DateTime.MaxValue;

        /// 
        /// Creates an instance with a specified key.
        /// 
        /// The key used for cryptographic functions, required 16 chars in length.
        public SecureQueryString(string key) : base()
        {
            mEncryptionUtil = new EncryptionUtility(key);
        }

        /// 
        /// Creates an instance with a specified key and an encrypted query string.
        /// 
        /// The key used for cryptographic functions, required 16 chars in length.
        /// An encrypted query string generated by a  instance.
        public SecureQueryString(string key, string queryString) : this(key)
        {
            Deserialize(DecryptAndVerify(queryString));
            CheckExpiration();
        }

        /// 
        /// Returns a encrypted query string.
        /// 
        /// 
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return EncryptAndSign(Serialize());
        }

        private void Deserialize(string queryString)
        {
            string[] nameValuePairs = queryString.Split('&');
            for (int i = 0; i <= nameValuePairs.Length - 1; i++) {
                string[] nameValue = nameValuePairs(i).Split('=');
                if (nameValue.Length == 2) {
                    base.Add(nameValue(0), nameValue(1));
                }
            }

            if (base.GetValues(timeStampKey) != null) {
                string[] strExpireTime = base.GetValues(timeStampKey);
                m_expireTime = Convert.ToDateTime(strExpireTime(0));
            }
        }

        private string Serialize()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string key in base.AllKeys) {
                sb.Append(key);
                sb.Append('=');
                sb.Append(base.GetValues(key)(0).ToString());
                sb.Append('&');
            }

            sb.Append(timeStampKey);
            sb.Append('=');
            sb.Append(m_expireTime.ToString(dateFormat));

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        private string DecryptAndVerify(string input)
        {
            return mEncryptionUtil.Decrypt(input);
        }

        private string EncryptAndSign(string input)
        {
            return mEncryptionUtil.Encrypt(input);
        }

        private void CheckExpiration()
        {
            if (DateTime.Compare(m_expireTime, DateTime.Now) < 0) {
                throw new ExpiredQueryStringException();
            }
        }

        /// 
        /// Gets or sets the timestamp in which this string should expire
        /// 
        public DateTime ExpireTime {
            get { return m_expireTime; }
            set { m_expireTime = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

> To encrypt some value and pass it to another action in MVC you would
>   do something like the below.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection collection)
{
    SecureQueryString qs = new SecureQueryString(mKey);

    qs('YourName') = collection('name');
    qs.ExpireTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2);

    Response.Redirect('Home.aspx/About?data=' + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(qs.ToString()));
}
```

> In the action that we redirect to, you would need to have this same
>   key and the query string value itself to decrypt it. Keep in mind that
>   if you don't have the correct key or if you try to decrypt the value
>   after the expiration, the class will throw an exception.

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    if (Request('data') != null) {
        try {
            SecureQueryString qs = new SecureQueryString(mKey, Request('data'));

            ViewData('Message') = 'Your name is ' + qs('YourName');
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

> I didn't spend much time explaining the source in depth because it has
>   been so long since I wrote it. Also keep in mind this was long before
>   my test first days ... (but it does appear to work)
>
> As always, the [source code](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/716525/content/downloads/EncryptionMVC.zip) for this sample is available for download.

Answer (score 10):

Use `HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode` and `HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode` to convert byte array to URL-safe string.

See [C# Byte[] to Url Friendly String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886686/c-byte-to-url-friendly-string).

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between encrypting and encoding; those methods weren't meant for encrypting.

Because encryption is hard to get right, and incredibly easy to get wrong (while still looking just as "encrypted" as the right solution), I recommend that you instead use GUID IDs:

http://www.calemadr.com/.../{6F0184E4-809F-4e30-8A5B-4DC144135A54}

SQL server has the uniqueidentifier type just for this case.

Comment: Seconded.  There's no point in using encryption on the ID's if the purpose is just obfuscation.

Comment: My apologies, I wasn't detailed enough in the question. I am trying to encode an encrypted string to be URL safe. Ironically, I am using Guids, the above encryption is a Guid. The problem is encoding an encrypted string that won't cause IIS to throw a security warning or appear to be a directory structure (contain slashes '/')

@Womp -Because of the nature of the system I have to encrypt the id.

Comment: Hmm. Why are you encrypting the GUID, then? If you're worried about someone who is not authorized reusing an URL, they could equally well reuse the URL you gave as an example. If you're worried about someone *guessing* someone else's GUID... never gonna happen.

Comment: @MarcelPopescu: I hope you understand the implication of having indexed GUIDs (either clustered or unclustered)... These indices are slower because SQL can't determine page by having the GUID alone. It automatically has to scan the whole index which is of course not the case when you use consecutinve index like `int identity`. That's the main reason people avoid using GUIDs.

Comment: @MarcelPopescu Maybe he is using [Sequential GUIDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

This post may be old but here you have another solution... 
When you are going to encrypt .ToBase64String, the url encode / decode change the encrypted string.

Try this on your encription library (or function) before doing the decode:

```
Myencodedid.Replace(' ', '+')
```

And then, go for the decryption!..

Answer (score 2):

First create one class like this:

```
public class Encryption
{ 
    public static string Encrypt(string clearText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return clearText;
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string cipherText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
        byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return cipherText;
    }
}
```

In Controller, add reference for this Ecription class like this:

```
using testdemo.Models

public ActionResult Index() {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string text)
        {
            if (Request["txtEncrypt"] != null)
            {
                string getEncryptionCode = Request["txtEncrypt"];
                string DecryptCode = Encryption.Decrypt(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(getEncryptionCode));
                ViewBag.GetDecryptCode = DecryptCode;
                return View();
            }
            else {
                string getDecryptCode = Request["txtDecrypt"];
                string EncryptionCode = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Encryption.Encrypt(getDecryptCode));
                ViewBag.GetEncryptionCode = EncryptionCode;
                return View();
            }

        }
```

In View:

```
<h2>Decryption Code</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table class="table-bordered table">
        <tr>
            <th>Encryption Code</th>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtEncrypt" name="txtEncrypt" placeholder="Enter Encryption Code" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <span style="color:red">@ViewBag.GetDecryptCode</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" id="btnEncrypt" name="btnEncrypt"value="Decrypt to Encrypt code" />
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
}
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <h2>Encryption Code</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table class="table-bordered table">
        <tr>
            <th>Decryption Code</th>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtDecrypt" name="txtDecrypt" placeholder="Enter Decryption Code" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <span style="color:red">@ViewBag.GetEncryptionCode</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" id="btnDecryt" name="btnDecryt" value="Encrypt to Decrypt code" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

I hope this useful.

Comment: The OP asked about URI encryption, not general Form field encryption

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised UrlEncode doesn't work.  What does the output of your encryption look like?

After you encrypt your Guid, try encoding it to Base64 with the [Convert.ToBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f9a8s97.aspx) method.  Then UrlEncode the Base64 string to make it an acceptable string to be included in your URL.

Comment: It might be better to just replace the / and + with - and _ for URLs, rather than urlencoding them.

Comment: But you also need to unencode, so then how would you know which - is a dash and which - is a slash?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... This probably won't make any difference but you could try the AntiXSS library and it's URLEncode() method.

http://www.codeplex.com/AntiXSS

HTHs,
Charles

Comment: I've used this library before. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it matters anymore to you but I just solved this problem on my own. I had to double urlencode.

For example

Server.UrlEncode(Server.UrlEncode(string to encode))

The problem seems to be that Request.Querystring(encoded string) automatically does a decode which is screwing up the encryption. I wish I could explain better but I'm still a little confused