# ASP .Net custom route not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, global-asax

ASP .Net custom route not working.

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        //default route
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

       //custom route
        routes.MapRoute(
         "Admin",
         "Admin/{addressID}",// controller name with parameter value only(exclude parameter name)
         new { controller = "Admin", action = "address" }
       new { addressID = @"\d+" }
     );
    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }


    public ActionResult address(int addressID = 0)
    {
     //code and redirection
    }
```

Here I want to hide everything from the url if possible...like i want to hide action name and parameter name and value if possible...
Suggest me the possible way to do this

Like I want URL like this (on priority basis)
1.http: //localhost:abcd/Admin 
or 
2.http: //localhost:abcd/Admin/address
or
3.http: //localhost:abcd/Admin/1
or
4.http: //localhost:abcd/Admin/address/1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1479505/1679410

Answer (score 1):

for quick reference.

- the custom route should appear before the default.
- try naming your custom rout as null.
  `routes.MapRoute(
      null, // Route name...`
- check that your calling the correct action.
- if youre dealing with actions that dont recieve a parameter upon initial load(example paging)
  makesure that your parameter is nullable  `address(int? addressID)`
  and on your custom route it should be like this

---

```
//custom route
    routes.MapRoute(
     null, //<<--- set to null
     "Admin/{addressID}",// controller name with parameter value only(exclude arameter name)
     new { controller = "Admin", action = "address" }
   //new { addressID = @"\d+" } <<--- no need for this because based from your example " 2.http: //localhost:abcd/Admin/address" the parameter can be null.
 );
```

thanks